# VMware, Output the Network HealthCheck in on CSV file

Tags: vmware

I have a script, it work perfectly and everything is show on my power shell screen "Console". But I try to figure Out how to export in CSV

Script:

foreach($vds in Get-VDSwitch)
        {
        $vds.ExtensionData.Runtime.HostMemberRuntime | %{
        $*.HealthCheckResult | where{$* -is [VMware.Vim.VMwareDVSVlanHealthCheckResult]} |
        Select @{N='vdSwitch';E={$vds.Name}},
            UplinkPortKey,
            @{N='TrunkedVLAN';E={
                ($*.TrunkedVLAN | %{
                    if($*.Start -eq $*.End){
                        "{0}" -f $*.Start
                    }
                    else{
                        "{0}-{1}" -f $*.Start,$*.End
                    }
                }) -join ','
            }}
          }

### }

### The Output on screen look like this;

VsanEnabled               : False
VsanDiskClaimMode         : Manual
HATotalSlots              : 3099
HAUsedSlots               : 22
HAAvailableSlots          : 1527
HASlotCpuMHz              : 32
HASlotMemoryMb            : 328
HASlotMemoryGB            : 0.3203125
HASlotNumVCpus            : 1
ParentId                  : Folder-group-h28
ParentFolder              : host
HAEnabled                 : True
HAAdmissionControlEnabled : True
HAFailoverLevel           : 1
HARestartPriority         : Medium
HAIsolationResponse       : DoNothing
VMSwapfilePolicy          : WithVM
DrsEnabled                : True
DrsMode                   : FullyAutomated
DrsAutomationLevel        : FullyAutomated
EVCMode                   : intel-nehalem
Name                      : mac01dmzp01
CustomFields              : {}
ExtensionData             : VMware.Vim.ClusterComputeResource
Id                        : ClusterComputeResource-domain-c12033
Uid                       : /VIServer=cn\t175726@mac01vcp02.cn.ca:443/Cluster=ClusterComputeResource-domain-c12033/

vdSwitch      : vds-toronto-mac01-2-ports-10Gbe
UplinkPortKey : 78
TrunkedVLAN   : 11-17,396,500

vdSwitch      : vds-toronto-mac01-2-ports-10Gbe
UplinkPortKey : 79
TrunkedVLAN   : 11-17,396,500

vdSwitch      : vds-toronto-mac01-2-ports-10Gbe
UplinkPortKey : 82
TrunkedVLAN   : 11-17,396,500

vdSwitch      : vds-toronto-mac01-2-ports-10Gbe
UplinkPortKey : 83
TrunkedVLAN   : 11-17,396,500

vdSwitch      : vds-toronto-mac01-2-ports-10Gbe
UplinkPortKey : 358
TrunkedVLAN   : 11-17,396,500

vdSwitch      : vds-toronto-mac01-2-ports-10Gbe
UplinkPortKey : 359
TrunkedVLAN   : 11-17,396,500

a lot more ......

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it, is with a function.

```
            #####################################################
            #  vSphere 6.5
            #  Get ESX HealthCheck Network Config from VDS
            #
            #  by Gerald Begin (Nov.20 2018)
            #################################

            ##### Set Script Location
            Set-Location T:\___Main-Script___\_VDS-vLANs_

            ##### Add VMWare Module.
            Get-Module -Name VMware* -ListAvailable | Import-Module

            ##### Output Path
            $Desti = 'T:\___Main-Script___\_VDS-vLANs_\Output'

            Import-Module -Name "T:\__Script_Functions__\Connect2All.ps1" -Force:$true      # Function to Connect to ALL vCenters

            $Clster = "mac01dmzp01"

            #### --------------------------------------

            function GetInfo  {
            ###################################################

            foreach($vds in Get-VDSwitch)
                    {
                    $vds.ExtensionData.Runtime.HostMemberRuntime | %{
                    $_.HealthCheckResult | where{$_ -is [VMware.Vim.VMwareDVSVlanHealthCheckResult]} |
                    Select @{N='vdSwitch';E={$vds.Name}},
                        UplinkPortKey,
                        @{N='TrunkedVLAN';E={
                            ($_.TrunkedVLAN | %{
                                if($_.Start -eq $_.End){
                                    "{0}" -f $_.Start
                                }
                                else{
                                    "{0}-{1}" -f $_.Start,$_.End
                                }
                            }) -join ','       
                        }}
                      }
                    }
                                }


            Get-Cluster -Name $Clster | GetInfo | Export-Csv -Path $Desti\Results.csv -NoTypeInformation

            Disconnect-VIServer * -Confirm:$false
```